# Do we need a [meteor] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Searching for Meteor-related questions turns up 33 posts; not a lot, but I'm sure I'm missing some. At least, I didn't find a useful match, so I posted my own question -- without the `meteor` tag because I'm still below the 300 mark.

Please consider making `meteor` a valid tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm taking a look now. I see [13 questions that contain the word "meteor"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=meteor%20is%3Aquestion). Of these, it only looks to me like 3 are questions that require any kind of expertise in Meteor.

I'm not going to say "no, we shouldn't have one". But so far, it hasn't seemed necessary. But if people don't agree with that and think we should have one, I (or any other user with 300 rep) can apply a tag.